# How to force TipKit to show a tip, regardless of history

Tags: swiftui, tipkit

I'm curious, is there a way to get TipKit to show a tip on-demand in a reliable way? I want a tip to appear only when the user taps on a help button, but I can't get it to happen consistently (ie after every single tap).

In this example code, it will work once on each launch, only because I've called `Tips.resetDatastore()` on initialisation. I would normally not want to be calling that. I'd rather that my Tooltip didn't store or use event history at all. But it should still respond to new events.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

struct extraHelp: Tip {
    static let tipRequested = Event(id: "extraHelpRequested")
    
    var title: Text { Text("Extra Help") }
    var message: Text { Text("Suitable amount of explanation here.")}
    
    var rules: [Rule] { [
        #Rule(Self.tipRequested) { $0.donations.count > 0 }
    ]}
    
    // This tip will always be visible when event received
    var options: [Option] {
        [IgnoresDisplayFrequency(true)]
    }
}


struct ViewWithOnScreenHelp: View {
    @State private var onscreenHelp = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Help!") {
                Task { await extraHelp.tipRequested.donate() }
            }
            .popoverTip(extraHelp())
        }
        .padding()
        .task { // This .task would normally go on the app root-view
            try? Tips.resetDatastore()     // not normal use
            try? Tips.configure([
                .displayFrequency(.immediate),
                .datastoreLocation(.applicationDefault),
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

I know that this isn't the way Apple wants me to use TipKit, but it's the UX I have in mind and it would be a shame to not be able to use the parts they've supplied.

Comment: I did some research a while ago and you need to set the trigger and then use something else to redraw the view. It is poor design from Apple since you can’t “present” on demand. Donate something then redraw and it will show.

Comment: That's disappointing that the design is so poor! I tried this, and it worked for a bit. But subsequent relaunches didn't work, so I'm not sure I have fully understood your solution. If you (or anyone else) has the time to do a full Answer with working code, that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Here is a sample I worked out for someone else, they want subsequent tips but the setup resets too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151667/multiple-popovertip-modifiers-in-swiftui-persistent-display-glitch/77208672#77208672

Comment: You could try `Tips.showTipsForTesting([myTip])`, but, as the name suggests, this is meant to be used for testing only. Not sure if it will work in release builds. You should definitely file Feedback, asking for an official way to do what you want. I think it's a good use case!

Comment: Just filed an enhancement request under FB13418895. Mirroring appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I will do so, as soon as I have a developer account.