TipKit triggers only every second donation although it is ruled for donations.count == 1
I have very simple Tips implemented which I want to trigger via a donation.
struct PopoverTipCheckGold: Tip {
    static let checkMoney = Event(id: "checkGold")
    
    let id: String = "4"
    var title: Text {
        Text("check your gold")
    }
    
    var message: Text? {
        Text("keep track of your gold.")
    }
    
    var rules: [Rule] {
        #Rule(Self.checkMoney) { event in
            event.donations.count == 1
        }
    }
}

In the simulator they everything works fine but on a physical device the tips only trigger when I activate them twice.
e.g. this code needs to run twice to show the Tip (e.g. pressing the button two times when the player does not have any money):
Task {await PopoverTipCheckGold.checkMoney.donate() }

if I double the line above in the simulator, the popup instantly disappears and on a physical device it never shows up. (expected behavior for the count == 2)
In the meantime I will use manual popup notifications, but it would be great to use the Tip functionality in the future, but it seems buggy to me.
   .overlay( OverlayIncome(game: game).opacity(0).popover(isPresented: $noGoldWarning, arrowEdge: .top) {
                VStack {
                    Text("not enough gold available").font(.custom("Montserrat-Bold", size:  15))
                    Text(" X current gold").font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 12))
                }
                .presentationCompactAdaptation(.none)
                    .padding()
            } , alignment: .top )


This has been a known issue for a white TipKit doesn’t actually trigger redraws so it is very prone to being out of sync.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151667/multiple-popovertip-modifiers-in-swiftui-persistent-display-glitch/77208672#77208672
